# printing polynomial equation in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to print a polynomial equation given list of terms in Prolog. 
For example, polynomial([exponent(3,4), exponent(10, 3)]) should be printed out 3X^4 + 10X^3. I wrote below code, the way I code prints '+' after the last term. If I print '+' before the next term, it prints '+' before the first term. How do I check this case?

```
printExponent(exponent(X1,X2)):-
     write(X1),
     X2 > 0,
          write('X^'),
          write(X2),
     write('').
 polynomial([]).
 polynomial([H|R]):-
      printExponent(H),
      polynomial(R).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle as base case of recursion a list of 1 element, instead of the empty one, so you can print the plus sign before calling the recursive rule

```
polynomial([H]) :-
  printExponent(H).
polynomial([H|R]):- 
  printExponent(H),
  write(+), 
  polynomial(R).
```

*edit* an advanced alternative, would be to use a DCG to relate the monomials' list and its representation:

```
:- use_module(library(dcg_util)).

polynomial(L, Cs) :-
    phrase(list(mono, plus, L), Cs).

mono(exponent(X1,X2)) --> {format(codes(Cs), '~w * X^~w', [X1,X2])}, Cs.
plus --> " + ".
```

example:

```
?- polynomial([exponent(2,3),exponent(5,6)],Cs),atom_codes(A,Cs).
Cs = [50, 32, 42, 32, 88, 94, 51, 32, 43|...],
A = '2 * X^3 + 5 * X^6'
```

I've used the handy pack [dcg_util](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=dcg_util) by M.Hendricks, a nice introduction to 'second order' DCGs (that is, passing non terminals as arguments).